# Async API giving worse performance

Tags: java, spring, api, testing, asynchronous

Interesting, I would think have 255 concurrent users, an async API would have better performance. Here are 2 of my endpoints in my Spring server:

```
@RequestMapping("/async")
public CompletableFuture<String> g(){
    CompletableFuture<String> f = new CompletableFuture<>();
    f.runAsync(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            f.complete("Finished");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    return f;
}

@RequestMapping("/sync")
public String h() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(500);
    return "Finished";
}
```

In the `/async` it runs it on a different thread. I am using `Siege` for load testing as follows:

`siege http://localhost:8080/sync --concurrent=255 --time=10S > /dev/null`

For the `async` endpoint, I got a transaction number of `27 hits`

For the `sync` endpoint, I got a transaction number of `1531 hits`

So why is this? Why isnt the async endpoint able to handle more transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the async endpoint is using a shared (the small `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`) threadpool to execute the sleeps, whereas the sync endpoint uses the larger threadpool of the application server. Since the common pool is so small, you're running maybe 4-8 operations (well, if you call sleeping an operation) at a time, while others are waiting for their turn to even get in the pool. You can use a bigger pool with `CompletableFuture.runAsync(Runnable, Executor)` (you're also calling the method wrong, it's a static method that returns a `CompletableFuture`).

Async isn't a magical "make things faster" technique. Your example is flawed as all the requests take 500ms and you're only adding overhead in the async one.

Comment: "Your example is flawed as all the requests take 500ms and you're only adding overhead in the async one." Yes all take 500ms, but at some point, I was hoping that async would be faster. How can I make a fair general test? Instead of using Thread.sleep, what else can I use to test accurately?

Comment: Have long running and short running operations. Async isn't magic "make all things faster" like I already said.

Comment: Yes, Im just doing this out of curiosity. When you say "long & short," what do you mean precisely? How many concurrent users should I have in the test?

Comment: I mean long running and short running. Instead of a single operation taking 500ms.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not seeming to understand. Care to give an example? I appreciate it

Comment: Short running: 300ms, long running 5000ms (FOR EXAMPLE). Then you can test with them being async or not in different combinations.

Comment: I see what you are saying now. In this case, however, how many concurrent users should I try out? The ForkJoinPool is still small, so it wouldn't make sense with 255 users since I would get the same issue wouldn't I?

Comment: Well would you? Only one way to find out. Also read my edit. And don't make the short running operation async.

Comment: Damn, this sucks. I changed `Thread.sleep(500)` to `Thread.sleep(5000)` and ran`siege http://localhost:8080/async -b --concurrent=100 --time=20S > /dev/null` load test for 20 seconds, but I am getting 0 hits/transactions now. Any idea?

Comment: Yea, read what I've written until you *understand*, then try again. I didn't say "change 500ms to 5000ms and do everything like you did before".

Comment: here is what I am thinking (of what you are saying): Try some *process* thats 5000ms, not `Thread.sleep(5000)` is that right?

Comment: No, that's not right. You can't get anything out of calling a **single** async endpoint regardless of users or the time it takes.

Comment: why not though? Are you saying I should make all endpoints async do a test (with long process) and then make all sync and do another test?

Comment: No, I told you to make a long taking endpoint async. But if you're only calling that, you're not going to benefit anything out of it.

Comment: Then what else should I be calling?

Comment: yes I get that, but my question is, should the different endpoint also be async?

Comment: Why don't you try it out and see.

Comment: thanks for keeping up with me! I appreciate every bit of support. I am trying mutliple things out now, created a general `/` endpoint that just returns a string, a non blocking and a blocking endpoint (with `Thread.sleep(5000)`) so now I am going to go do some more tests!

Comment: This is one of the tests `http://localhost:8080/sync, http://localhost:8080/` where it randomly selects a URL. This is another:  `http://localhost:8080/async, http://localhost:8080/`


My confusion is that I'm still not getting as many transactions with the second test as the first.